# how to use beautifulsoup to fetch data in slim scroll window

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Recently I came across a problem of trying to fetch data from slim scroll window in a website. I can see all the tags and their class/id/type in Chrome Inspect element with not problem.

The webpage is https://chart.cryptocoinsnews.com/bitfinex_frame.html
The table I am looking at is
[image: html code near the table]

From soup, I can still visit the parent `{div class="panel-body table-pannel-body"}` but not this tag `{div class = "slimScrollDiv" style=........}` which contains the table I am interested.

It is confusing to me why I can see them on Chrome but would not be able to fetch by soup. Appreciate if anyone could help. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Due to it's dynamic nature the table is being created/updated from javascript.

You are likely only downloading the HTML before the DOM is constructred dynamically with javascript. So you'll need to use a browser, e.g. with `selenium`, to *see* the same DOM that you can have in chrome.

Note that selenium can use headless browsers, like PhantomJS.

Comment: Thanks a lot memoselyk!!

Comment: Thanks a lot memoselyk!! Very important information from you. I didn't realize it was the javascript format making beautiful soup invalid. I guess both selenium and phantonjs are right approach to my problem. But when I was researching online I found about directly using json to uncover data from these website. Actually that solves my problem even more efficient since the data based on jason (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qbEN3boz7_M) is way easier to deal with then conventional html format. I guess I love this quick and dirty way :D But thank to your initial information again!